# Android ListView, Contacts and Own Data table

Tags: android, listview

Currently I'm pulling out all my contacts and displaying it in a ListView. Next, for each contact in the list I do a check with my own table and display an icon if he is a registered user. So far I have tried the following ways:

1) In the getView() of the adapter, for each row, I call a query on my own table by passing in the contact id. The slows down the scrolling of the ListView and might run into memory issues.

2) In the getView(), for each row, i add the contact id & image view to a queue which does the query 1 by 1 and display the icon. This sorta works but sometimes the display gets weird and randomly shows the icon then disappear.

3) I used a MatrixCursor and tried to join the data but the query in step 1 is called too so it slows down the display again.

Anyone can comment or give a better suggestion would be great! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check Google IO video on listview performance: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Basically, what you need to do is 2 things:

1. Implement your own CursorAdapter that holds to your data and attaches it to items as tags. That will speed up scrolling a lot, will look up data only once. Otherwise you hit your table every time item comes into view. Android OS aggresive about disposing items.. This called viewholder pattern, see it discussed here: [android listview viewholder. when to use it, and when not to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208897/android-listview-viewholder-when-to-use-it-and-when-not-to) I didn't find better example but you get an idea..
2. I would cache items from your database into List so you don't have to query for each item.

Comment: I actually did 1 and 2, was wondering if there is a better way? I was thinking if it is possible to somehow join the data of the Contacts and my table together to produce 1 cursor so that the checking easier and faster.

Comment: Slowdown most likely when you lookup attribute per each record. I doubt you can join data because you use ContentProvider but you can sync data from contacts into your database and than look up everything from your own database. But I think this would be last resort. If you have your data "handy" and don't go to database on each call it should be pretty fast

Comment: I've been facing the problem of having it "handy" so far....oh well, thanks anyway, i will stick to accessing the db until i can think of something.