# How to optimize Android ListView?

Tags: android, listview

I have customized my ListAdapter and i show 3 different Images (items) in 1 row.
It works perfectly (according to it's function).
However, it's not possible to scroll the ListView smoothly.

I am using setBackgroundImage on ImageViews and i use an HashMap to cache resourceId; so i don't have to use

`resId=getContext().getResources().getIdentifier(resName, "drawable",appContext.getPackageName());`

again and again.

I think i am missing something as the ListView is not scrolling well. Also if i try it on a tablet where my code automatically fills more than 3 items on a row, tablet's listview is almost unscrollable.

What am i doing wrong here?

**UPDATE:**

I create ListView programmatically in my Flags (country flags) Activity's onCreate method:

`root=(ViewGroup)this.findViewById(R.id.root);`

```
    listView=new ListView(this);
    listView.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));

    /*
    ArrayList<Country> dataList=new ArrayList<Country>(){{
        add(new Country("jp"));
        add(new Country("de"));
        add(new Country("it"));
    }};*/

    CountryListAdapter countryListAdapter=new CountryListAdapter(this);


    countryListAdapter.setDataSource(allCountries);


    listView.setAdapter(regionListAdapter);
    listView.setBackgroundColor(0xFF000000);
    listView.setDividerHeight(0);

    root.addView(listView);
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not well" and "smoothly"?

Comment: Show us at least the code where you create the view for the ListView item.

Comment: Use Traceview to determine precisely where you are spending your time. Also, ativate `StrictMode` to yelp at you regarding obvious problems on the main application thread.

Comment: For better smooth scrolling use [ViewHolder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) and Background thread. You may like to check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3208897/android-listview-viewholder-when-to-use-it-and-when-not-to/17485652#comment30104745_17485652) one.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Study, study and study ;-)

And my **tip** is to use **ViewHolder** pattern, for large number of item's of same layout (even if it is the simpliest one, such as single TextView)

- Google I/O 2009 - ...Make your Android UI Fast and Efficient http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N6YdwzAvwOA
- Google I/O 2010 - The world of ListView http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70
- http://www.technotalkative.com/category/android/listview/
- [ViewHolder - good practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13164054/view-holder-good-practice)
- [why does the ViewHolder pattern work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5973917/why-does-the-viewholder-pattren-work)
- [Is it crucial for performance to have ViewHolder as static in a ViewHolder pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12368302/is-it-crucial-for-performance-to-have-viewholder-as-static-in-a-viewholder-patte)

And also this `ViewHolder` implementation example/library

- https://github.com/rtyley/android-viewholder-listviews (Apache 2.0)

Also if you do use images in your ListView items layout, you can use some libraries to download images asynchronously, such as:

- https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader
- [Lazy load of images in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012)
- http://android-developers.blogspot.cz/2010/07/multithreading-for-performance.html

Answer (score 4):

1. **Use static ViewHolder pattern**
2. **Inflating layout is expensive task so avoid inflating layout as much as possible**
   **Replace**

   ```
   LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
   convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
   ```

   **With**

   ```
   if (convertView == null) {

       LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
       convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listview_item, null);
   }
   ```
3. **Do image loading task in seperate thread so getView only focus on View drawing**
4. **add `<item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>` in your activity theme**
5. **add property `android:animationCache="false"` in ListView**
6. **add property `android:scrollingCache="false"` in ListView**

Answer (score 2):

You should use the [View Holder](http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html) pattern, also test if the scrolling is slow without the debugger connected.